# How to set View height as percentage of the screen height in Storyboards with XCode 7

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard, interface-builder, uistoryboard

I need to design the view like below image and I have tried with fixed heights and also tried compact width and regular height and regular width and compact height but those scenarios did not worked for me.

How can i set View height as percentage of the screen height in Storyboards?

I'm using Xcode 7

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Basically you need to act on the `multiplier` property of an height equal constraint. To do that while pressing CTRL, drag from the view to its superview and select `equal heights constraint`, later edit this constraint in Size Inspector by setting its `multiplier`  the desired value can be expressed also as 1:25, 1/25, 0,025. If it working on the contrary just reverse items as in the picture.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can simply set the height of each one as a ratio of the UI height, 15% height would be;

```
.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.15)
```

Answer (score -1):

Programmatic version

```
- (void)overallViewConstratints {

_firstView = [[UIView alloc]init];
[_firstView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
_firstView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[self.view addSubview:_firstView];

NSLayoutConstraint *firstViewTop = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_firstView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];

NSLayoutConstraint *firstViewLeading = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_firstView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];

NSLayoutConstraint *firstViewTrailing = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_firstView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];

NSLayoutConstraint *firstViewHeight = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_firstView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:0.15 constant:0.0];

NSArray *firstViewConstraints = @[firstViewTop, firstViewLeading, firstViewTrailing, firstViewHeight];
[self.view addConstraints:firstViewConstraints];

_secondView = [[UIView alloc]init];
_secondView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
[self.secondView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.view addSubview:_secondView];

NSLayoutConstraint *secondViewTop = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_secondView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:_firstView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];

NSLayoutConstraint *secondViewLeading = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_secondView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];

NSLayoutConstraint *secondViewTrailing = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_secondView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];

NSLayoutConstraint *secondViewHeight = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_secondView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:0.25 constant:0.0];

NSArray *secondViewConstraints = @[secondViewTop, secondViewLeading, secondViewTrailing, secondViewHeight];
[self.view addConstraints:secondViewConstraints];


_thirdView = [[UIView alloc]init];
_thirdView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
[_thirdView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.view addSubview:_thirdView];


NSLayoutConstraint *thirdViewTop = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_thirdView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:_secondView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];

NSLayoutConstraint *thirdViewLeading = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_thirdView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];

NSLayoutConstraint *thirdViewTrailing = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_thirdView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];

NSLayoutConstraint *thirdViewHeight = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_thirdView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:0.40 constant:0.0];

NSArray *thirdViewConstraints = @[thirdViewTop, thirdViewLeading, thirdViewTrailing, thirdViewHeight];
[self.view addConstraints:thirdViewConstraints];


_fourthView = [[UIView alloc]init];
_fourthView.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];
[_fourthView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.view addSubview:_fourthView];


NSLayoutConstraint *fourthViewTop = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_fourthView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:_thirdView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];

NSLayoutConstraint *fourthViewLeading = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_fourthView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];

NSLayoutConstraint *fourthViewTrailing = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_fourthView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];

NSLayoutConstraint *fourthViewHeight = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_fourthView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:0.20 constant:0.0];

NSArray *fourthViewConstraints = @[fourthViewTop, fourthViewLeading, fourthViewTrailing, fourthViewHeight];
[self.view addConstraints:fourthViewConstraints];
}
```