# How to add a sibling view in Visual Studio Xamarin.ios designer?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017

This is my first Xamarion.IOS project and I have a view controller with the following heirarchy:

[image]

View Controller with an "Outer" Stack View (Parent).

This outer stack view should have two children:

- Child1 - a View taking up the top 30% of the screen which I've also managed to add as you can see below.
- Child2 - another Stack View taking up the remaining 70% of the screen.

The problem is in Visual Studio 2017 designer when I try to drag a Stack View onto the Parent, it gets set as a child of Child1 because Child1 is taking up the full space of the Parent so there's no space to drag it unto Parent.

I tried playing around with the properties of both Child1 and Parent so that there is some space to add Child2 to Parent but I haven't been successful so far. I could do that by removing AutoLayout for the whole storyboard but I want to keep that setting as I am porting from an XCode project which has the setting and I don't want to screw around. Also seems a bit overkill that I have to remove AutoLayout everytime I need to add a sibling.

There doesn't seem to be a way to drag the view size to limit it's height. Even the "Fill Parent" buttons on the Layout tab cannot be "unchecked". Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to add the constraints to your Child1 and Child2. Check how in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36042422/2364774)